# orientation from acceleration?

Tags: rotations, orientation

I have an object that has a sensor attached on it. This sensor calculates the acceleration in all axis and angular acceleration in all axis(Keep the gravity force in mind). How can I get the Pitch, Yaw and Roll(Orientation) from the known acceleration and angular acceleration values?

Answer (score 0):

There is a body of literature on producing the navigation solution from these kind of inertial measurement sensors. Pitch, yaw and roll are interdependent outcomes of a double integration process that takes into account the interplay between the different components and the object they are attached to.

Gravity is a useful indicator in some situations and a distraction in others. Similarly the Earth's rotation can be important. One interesting effect of such a system is that measuring while stationary can be used to estimate the latitude, from the angle between the gravity vector and the Earth rotation vector.